# google map not load into bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I am working with modal bootstrap, where I need to load a googlemap, however I just do as normal must load, and console shows me that maps it is being loaded but, the element inspection show the element which must load the map empty, like the image

[image: Screenshot of the map container and the result of inspect the container and map variable that show that the map has been loaded]

The code used for my map is

```
var map;

var drawingManager;
var selectedShape;

function initializeMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-16.4237766667, -71.54262),
        zoom : 15,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),
            mapOptions);
    console.debug(map);
}
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            initializeMap();
            $('#createleaf').click(function() {
                $('#modalFence').modal('show');
            });
            $('#modalFence').on('shown',function(event) {
                //console.debug(map);
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
                var modal = $(this);
                modal.css('margin-top',(modal.outerHeight() / 2) * -1)
                .css('margin-left',(modal.outerWidth() / 2) * -1);
                return this;
            });
        });
```

One more thing, I just try to create the map outside the modal, I mean on the page, and it runs well, the problem is just on the modal

My full code is on [external link](http://pastebin.com/2qkMZ93a) in order to not make the post too long

Thanks a lot

Comment: Put more HTML code or play it on JSFiddle

Comment: I have paste my full code on http://pastebin.com/2qkMZ93a

Comment: Does the map have a size (when you trigger the resize event)?

Comment: yes, it has a height of 420px and a width of 100%

Comment: I have paste my whole code

Comment: Try to call `initializeMap();` at the beginning of the function `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I just tried that, but it is strange.. cause the inspector shows the var map with the map object, however the div container apear empty

Comment: I just found the error, It was a typewriting, I have noticed that the lines 246-256 in the paste bin, contains a modal with the same id map container, that is the reason on why my modal was not displaying the map, cause it was being loaded on the first one container with the same id
Tanks a lot to all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the error, It was a typewriting, I have noticed that the lines 246-256 in the paste bin, contains a modal with the same id map container, that is the reason on why my modal was not displaying the map, cause it was being loaded on the first one container with the same id Tanks a lot to all of you

Comment: and the pastebin is removed :H